# manual pagination of raw queries laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

Am trying to create manual pagination for raw queries in laravel.Checking the laravel docs, i saw that using the method Paginator like :`

$applicants = Paginator::make($applicants,$totalApplicants,4);`

But when i return $applicants it gives me all the records and not the 4 as requested in my Paginator::make method but if i call the links() mehod on my applicants like : $applicants->links() it returns the link to the pagination to my view

Please what am i doing wrong or do i need to write a mehod to make this work

Code from My Controller:

```
$statement3 = "SELECT * FROM applicant where lga = '$appulga' ";

        //loop through lga id to build query
        foreach($LGA_Names as $lga)
        {
            $statement3.= " "."OR"." "."lga=". "'".$lga."'";
        }

        //FAcility for User assigned LGA
        $applicants = DB::Select($statement3);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $totalApplicants = count($applicants);
        $perpage = 4;

        $applicants = Paginator::make($applicants,$totalApplicants,$perpage);
```

Comment: Can you share more code? `$applicants` must be an array

Comment: just shared code from my controller

Answer (score 1):

Paginator does not split collections, you must process your results manually.

```
$page = Paginator::getCurrentPage(); // Get the current page for the request

$limit = 4;
$offset = $page * $limit;

// query to get `COUNT(*)`
// query to get results with `LIMIT $offset, $limit`

Paginator::make($results, $total, $limit);
```

writing sql queries manually ineffective and not safe, use query builder instead;

```
$query = DB::table('applicant')->where('lga', $appulga);

foreach ($LGA_Names as $lga)
{
    $query->orWhere('lga', $lga);
}

$applicants = $query->paginate(4);
```

Comment: actually my query is more complicated than you see it.i have to generates lga based on user login id then generates facility from facility databse then finally applicants from applicants table.so using eloquent queries is out of my option

Answer (score 1):

You have obtained all records because you call `Paginator::make` with `$applicants`, you may try something like this:

```php
$pageNumber = Input::get('page', 1);
$perpage = 4;


$statement = "SELECT * FROM applicant where lga = '$appulga' ";
// ...
$applicants = DB::Select($statement);


$slice = array_slice($applicants, $perpage * ($pageNumber - 1), $perpage);
$applicants = Paginator::make($slice, count($applicants), $perpage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Paginator calculate pagination links, so it does not effect your query.

What it returns only `/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator` object and if you wanna return as response or pass to view, it will return array elements which is defined in [toArray](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php#L512) method.